# PhoneGap SQLite error? Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I m developing Android application. I'm integrating the sqlite into my application https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-sqlitePlugin-Android
The below error is coming

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'exec'

while using the following code

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "DB"});
```

Comment: why arent't you using the official websql api? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: But it is limited to 5MB for that we are moving to SQLite

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The official websql api provides also a SQLite Database with a default size of 5MB, but it's not limited to it. You can even create a DB until 500MB I think, see: http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Comment: Yes correct but some android devices are not accepting more than 5MB.That is the problem in web sql.

Comment: @kanna did u solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you have waited for Cordova to load prior to opening a database.

As per the [README.md from the project](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin):

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/xuexueMaGicK/Gift-App

see this link js file is available here database connection are there

```
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
pageshow = document.createEvent("Event");
pageshow.initEvent("pageshow", true, true);

tap = document.createEvent("Event");
tap.initEvent("tap", true, true);

pages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="page"]');
numPages = pages.length;

links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="link"]');
numLinks = links.length;

//checkDB();
document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkDB, false);
 }
```

/***********************************
       General Interactions
***********************************/

```
 function checkDB() {
 navigator.splashscreen.hide();

 database = openDatabase('data', '', 'data', 1024 * 1024);

 if (database.version === '') {

    database.changeVersion('', '1.0', createDB, function (tx, err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }, function (tx, rs) {
        console.log("Increment transaction success.");
    });
    addNavHandlers();
} else {
    addNavHandlers();
}
```

}

```
function createDB(db) 
{

/*******Create Table Gifts********/

 db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE "gifts" ("gift_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name_id" INTEGER, "occasion_id" INTEGER, "gift_idea" VARCHAR(45))', [], function (tx, rs) {
    console.log("Table gifts created");
}, function (tx, err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
/*******Create Table Names********/
db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE "names" ("name_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name_text" VARCHAR(80))', [], function (tx, rs) {
    console.log("Table names created");
}, function (tx, err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
/*******Create Table Occasions********/
db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE "occasions" ("occasion_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "occasion_text" VARCHAR(80))', [], function (tx, rs) {
    console.log("Table occasions created");
}, function (tx, err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest.xml u have to add plugins related to the SQLite.Then it will work.